# iOS) NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access

```
NSDictionary *argsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:coupon.couponID, @"id",coupon.couponMart,@"marketname",coupon.couponItem,@"name",coupon.couponDescription,@"description",coupon.couponItemImageString,@"image",coupon.couponIssuedDate,@"issued",coupon.couponUsedDate,@"used",coupon.couponExpiredDate,@"expiration",coupon.state,@"valid", nil];
```

I have bad access at that code above

Can you recognize it?

I think it's perfect

Comment: You have to add more code for it. what is coupon !

Comment: your coding is correct , check once the **coupon.xxxx** are  empty or null

Comment: @AshishKakkad is right, you need to add more code.  You also need to give us the exact error.

Comment: It would also not hurt to use ObjC literal syntax. Makes it easier read.

Comment: @AshishKakkad coupon is my datamodel!

Comment: And I found that every data is not empty or null... that's very sad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you init a NSDictionary is right.

The error shows you got bad access, which means where you use the dictionary is not correct.

You should check the value before you are about to use it. Things like that

```
if([argsDict objectForKey:@"id"] != nil) {
    myLabel.text = [argsDict objectForKey:@"id"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may getting any nil value from "coupon" property.also make sure you initialized coupon class.